# Sqlite Query Error

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am using sqlite db in android.
In this I need to give Id as autoincrement and second 'Incoming_sms' field as primary key. but it shows me error as below:

```
detailMessage "near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error:  
CREATE TABLE TwoWayTable111 (
  ID INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT,  
  INCONMING_MSG TEXT PRIMARY KEY,  
  OUTGOING_MSG TEXT,  
  STATUS TEXT )"
```

Why does this error occur? But when I give id as autoincrement and primary key, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1). It works as designed. This statement returns a syntax error.

```
create table test (id integer autoincrement);
```

This one runs without error.

```
create table test (id integer primary key autoincrement);
```

You should be able to do this.

```
CREATE TABLE TwoWayTable111 (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    INCONMING_MSG TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    OUTGOING_MSG TEXT, 
    STATUS TEXT );
```